# Ideal time for timeToLiveSeconds in Eache?

Tags: java, caching, db2, sybase

My Manager is asking to use cache to reduce the calls between the database and server and asking to keep the timeToLiveSeconds for 24hrs as the data in the tables is more consistent.

But I have 2 questions

1) I always saw the max time of cache timeToLiveSeconds is 10 minutes.Is it a good Idea to refresh the cache for every 24hrs?

2)This is Java application with websphere server and the database is Sybase and in near future they are planning to change the database to DB2. Is there any trigger which works as "For all DML actions on the table, that clears the cache?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sybase was a company that produced a number of different database products.  It would be helpful to know which Sybase database product you are referring to and tag your question accordingly ([sybase-ase],[sybase-iq],[sqlanywhere],etc)

Comment: here they are using Sybase SQL